# MySQL: How to get user with most wins?

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a table with the following fields: id, opp1, opp2, opp1_votes, opp2_votes.

If one of the opps have more votes than another so we consider that he won. How can I get opp with most wins from this table?

Comment: Your question is strange. We are used to having a table like (id, opp, opp_votes), and find the max. Why are the columns duplicated?

Comment: probably because there are 2 opponents against each other that he is storing.

Comment: I suppose it is a preferential voting system

Comment: Yes, it is 2 opponents against each other. And sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will find the number of wins for each user, and order them in a descending order (so the one with most wins will be the first row):

```
SELECT winner, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT opp1 AS winner FROM table
    WHERE opp1_votes > opp2_votes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT opp2 AS winner FROM table
    WHERE opp2_votes > opp1_votes
    )
GROUP BY winner
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Explanation of the query:

1. First, we find all the rows for which opp1 was the winner. We generate a table where the opp1 winners are listed under the field name "winner".
2. We do the same as in (1), but now for cases where opp2 was the winner.
3. We UNION the two table and receive a list of all winners in all games.
4. Now, we group the resulting table by winner ID, and select the count out from this grouping, resulting in a list of winners, and for each one the number of times he/she won.
5. The last step is ordering by by the number of wins, descending.

Notes:

- According to the query above, if there's a tie - there's no winner. If you want to treat ties as wins for one of the users, you'll need to define a tie-breaking heuristic.
- If you really only want a single result, you can start with `SELECT TOP 1 winner, ...` or finish with `LIMIT 1`, but as far as I know it will not save computation time in the general case, so I'll leave it.

Comment: Your 'ORDER BY' clause is missing the word 'BY' ;)

Comment: when an opp is winner as opp1 then also as opp2, the UNION erases that as it filter duplicates. I think you should put a 'UNION ALL'

Comment: I'm getting "1" in column COUNT(*) for every winner

Comment: @Konstantin: did you use **UNION ALL** as in my refactored answer? You probably used the previous **UNION** (thanks again najmeddine)

Comment: You're right, i didn't notice it. Many thanks to you, your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT opp, sum(win) wins FROM ( 
    SELECT opp1 opp, CASE WHEN opp1_votes > opp2_votes THEN 1 ELSE 0 END win
      FROM otable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT opp2 opp, CASE WHEN opp2_votes > opp1_votes THEN 1 ELSE 0 END win
      FROM otable
) A
GROUP BY opp
ORDER BY sum(win) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Not sure if this is possible for the specific database in question, but this approach could fail if the same opponent can appear in opp1 for some rows and opp2 on other rows.

Comment: I think you have a parenthesis issue on the SUM lines.

Comment: @jbourque - that's fine, you just want to make sure that for each row, you either return it in the first case (opp1 wins) or the second case (opp2 wins). You won't be able to tell after the UNION which position the winner was in.

Comment: I made some refactoring. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN opp1_votes > opp2_votes THEN opp1 ELSE opp2 END as winner,
    COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY CASE WHEN opp1_votes > opp2_votes THEN opp1 ELSE opp2 END
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This little query will get you all the winners and the number of times he's won in descending order:

```
SELECT
(CASE WHEN `opp1_votes`>`opp2_votes` THEN `opp1` ELSE `opp2` END) `winner`,
COUNT(*) AS `no_of_times`
FROM `matches`
GROUP BY `winner`
ORDER BY `no_of_times` DESC
```

What we are doing here is:

1. compare find out which one is greater from opp1_votes and opp2_votes in a CASE WHEN clause
2. If opp1_votes is higher then we output opp1 in the `winner` column and vice versa
3. Then we group the results by winner
4. Now if count the number of rows each winner has we get the number wins by each winner
5. The the results are ordered by no_of_times won

If you want just the person with most number of wins you can add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query or you can wrap the above query and select max(no_of_times) from it like below:

```
SELECT `winner`, MAX(`no_of_times`) AS `no_of_times` FROM (
SELECT
(CASE WHEN `opp1_votes`>`opp2_votes` THEN `opp1` ELSE `opp2` END) `winner`,
COUNT(*) AS `no_of_times`
FROM `matches`
GROUP BY `winner`
ORDER BY `no_of_times` DESC
) AS `winners`
```

Comment: Yes but this will be faster but guess that doesn't always matter. Well I enjoyed making this answer anyway so no worries

Answer (score -2):

Does this do what you want it to?

```
select top 1 opp1, 
   (select count(*) 
      from table i 
      where i.opp1 = o.opp1 and i.opp1votes > i.opp2votes) as wins 
from table o 
order desc by wins
```

Comment: there's no need to check for opp2 cause I'm assuming there's a mirrored entry somewhere else in the table right? else i don't fully understand your dataset

Comment: No, here's how it works: somebody starts a battle and he is considered as opp1, then someone joins him and the second one considered as opp2. But every one can start or join battle, so one person can be opp1 or opp2 in different cases.

Comment: ahh, ok.  now i understand more...then i think someone else already has the solution then.  i won't bother posting it again ;)  i thought there were two entries for each game. one where a player is opp1 and another from the other perspective where he/she is opp2