# List elements by largest number of conditional occurrences using sqlalchemy's ORM

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider a database containing a record of ping-pong games played.
The database has two tables:

- users

  - name (string), primary key
- games

  - id (int), primary key
  - playerA_id (string): foreign key to users.name
  - playerB_id (string): foreign key to users.name
  - scoreA (int): PlayerA's score for this game.
  - scoreB (int): PlayerB's score for this game.

We describe these tables in sqlalchemy as follows:

```
class User(Base):
    """A user"""

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    name = Column(String(USER_NAME_LEN), primary_key=True)


class Game(Base):
    """A game"""

    __tablename__ = 'games'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    playerA_id = Column(String(USER_NAME_LEN), ForeignKey('users.name'))
    playerB_id = Column(String(USER_NAME_LEN), ForeignKey('users.name'))

    playerA = relationship("User", backref=backref("games"),
                           foreign_keys=[playerA_id])
    playerB = relationship("User", backref=backref("games"),
                           foreign_keys=[playerB_id])

    scoreA = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    scoreB = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

We'd like to generate a list of players and their total number of wins.
The SQL to do this is something like (see [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477123/mysql-how-to-get-user-with-most-wins))

```
SELECT winner, COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT playerA_id AS winner FROM games
    WHERE scoreA > scoreB
    UNION ALL
    SELECT playerB_id AS winner FROM games
    WHERE scoreB > scoreA
    )
GROUP BY winner
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

How is this done using sqlalchemy's ORM and queries?